# Auto complete JQuery line separator

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

i am already populating the autocomplete words and i wanted to have a line separator between the words for better identification in the auto complete.
Say the value in the drop down should be rendered as

```
         Brijesh
         -------
         John
         -------
         Mike
```

Below is the snippet

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#studentName").autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Webservice.asmx/GetStudentNames",
        data: "{'prefixText':'" + request.term + "'}",
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function (data) {
       var regex = new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + request.term.replace(/([\^\$\(\)\[\]\{\}\*\.\+\?\|\\])/gi, "\\$1") + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi");
            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                return {
                label: item.split('|')[0].replace(regex, "<Strong>$1</Strong>"),
                val: item.split('|')[1]
                }
            }))
        },

        failure: function (response) {
            ServiceFailed(result);
        }
    });
},
select: function (event, ui) {
 txtStudent(ui.item.val, ui.item.label); //Student name and id used in this method
},
minLength: 2
});
});
```

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: CSS would be a better solution here IMO, rather than appending 'unselectable' options. Just add `border-bottom: 1px solid #000; margin: 5px 0;` to each element in the dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

How about simulating the separator with CSS.  Something like:

```
autocomplete option {
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

Comment: i need a solid line and the line should touch the vertical borders of the dropdown box

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS

```
.ui-menu-item{
   border-bottom: 1px dotted black;  
}
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/JRM5Y/

Comment: i need a solid line and the line should touch the vertical borders of the dropdown box